# Quadratic reciprocity in characteristic 2

Tags: nt.number-theory

Given a polynomial $a(t)\in F_2[t]$, for which irreducible $f(t)\in F_2[t]$ does
the trace of $a(t)\bmod f(t)$ equal 0/1? By Artin reciprocity applied to the extension
defined by $x^2-x-a(t)$ it should depend only on the residue of $f(t)$ modulo some conductor,
but what does this reciprocity law look like explicitly for this case?

Comment: Is http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/ugradnumthy/QRchar2.pdf of any help? (Sorry, I have absolutely no time to check myself.)

Comment: Gee Darij, I hope it is. :)